# How reset multiple scroll down selected menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, coffeescript, reset

I've 2 scroll down menus like

```
<%= f.label :term_id, "TERM *"%>
    <br>
<%= f.collection_select :term_id, Term.order(:id), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
    <br>
<%= f.label :lesson_id, "LESSON *" %>
    <br>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :lesson_id, Term.order(:name), :lessons, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: "Ders Seçiniz" %>
```

and the javascript code is like that

```
jQuery ->
  lessons = $('#demand_lesson_id').html()
  $('#demand_term_id').change ->
    term = $('#demand_term_id :selected').text()
    options = $(lessons).filter("optgroup[label='#{term}']").html()
    if options
      $('#demand_lesson_id').html(options)
    else
      $('#demand_lesson_id').empty()
```

I need to reset when I click to reset button. but all forms elements are cleaned except lessons group collection.

How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

The form reset button *should* restore all your select's default options. But if you need something to override whatever it is overriding the reset button behaviour, here's some plain old jQuery (Sorry, but I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript).

See it at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/nHJLH/1/)

```
$(function(){

    // reset button click
    $('#myReset').click(function(){

        // cycle through each option and restore to default
        $('#myForm select option').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('defaultSelected'));
        });
    });
});
```